# how to change the default browser in webbrowser module

Tags: python

I am using webbrowser module and it is showing this error

```
File "C:\Users\ADITYA\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\webbrowser.py", line 65, in get
    raise Error("could not locate runnable browser")
webbrowser.Error: could not locate runnable browser
```

in line 8 where I have written

```
webbrowser.get('chrome')
```

Answer (score 0):

I came across this question  when entering my question - how to use a different default browser with Panel module - and I have found the following solution which should change default web browser for any python module using webbrowser as well I think if the order is preserved i.e change webbrowser settings before using the module. In my case the default browser was chrome and wanted to use edge since webdriver manager is broken for chrome but works for edge as of this post.

```
import webbrowser
import panel as pn

# Register Microsoft Edge as the browser to use
webbrowser.register('edge', None, webbrowser.BackgroundBrowser("C://Program Files (x86)//Microsoft//Edge//Application//msedge.exe"))

#  
webbrowser.get('edge')
# reverse trying  order since edge got added to the end of the list
webbrowser._tryorder.reverse()

pn.extension()

# Show the Panel in the browser
bokeh_server = pn.pane.Markdown('## Hello, World!').show()
```